# Unable to implement search feature on a custom list view

Tags: android, list, custom-adapter, custom-lists

I am making a custom listView and i take a edit text on the top of list view to search the items in list view but when i enter any value in edit text it search in list view but when i clear the edit test it **does not show the original list view**
my main activity code is

```html
package com.example.searchonlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher  {

 private FriendListAdapter friendListAdapter;
 private EditText inputSearch;
 private ListView friendList;
 private ArrayList<String> frndArrList;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
  inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(this);

  frndArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
  frndArrList.add("Ashutosh");
  frndArrList.add("ShreeVridhee");
  frndArrList.add("Tanishi");
  frndArrList.add("Divyanu");
  frndArrList.add("Adarsh");
  frndArrList.add("Akshara");
  frndArrList.add("Pooja");
  frndArrList.add("NoOne");

  friendList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  friendListAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(this, frndArrList);
  friendList.setAdapter(friendListAdapter);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
   int after) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

  Log.e("EditText", s.toString());

  friendListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

 }

 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

 }
 
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

and my list adapter is

```html
package com.example.searchonlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
 MainActivity context;
 ArrayList<String> frndArrList;
 ArrayList<String> filterArrList;
 private FriendFilter friendFilter;

 public FriendListAdapter(MainActivity context, ArrayList<String> frndArrList) {
  this.context = context;
  this.frndArrList = frndArrList;
  this.filterArrList = frndArrList;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {

  return frndArrList.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {

  return position;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {

  return position;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_view, parent, false);
  TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.inflate_txtView);
  txtView.setText(frndArrList.get(position));

  return view;
 }

 @Override
 public Filter getFilter() {
  if (friendFilter == null)
   friendFilter = new FriendFilter();

  return friendFilter;

 }

 private class FriendFilter extends Filter {

  @Override
  protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
     FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
     
     if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
           // No filter implemented we return all the list
      
           results.values = frndArrList;
           results.count = frndArrList.size();
       }
   
     else {
           // We perform filtering operation
           ArrayList<String> nPlanetList = new ArrayList<String>();
           for (String p : frndArrList) {
            Log.v("String", p);
               if (p.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                   nPlanetList.add(p);
               Log.e("nPlanetList", nPlanetList.toString());
           }
            
           results.values = nPlanetList;
           results.count = nPlanetList.size();
    
       }
   return results;
   
  }

  @Override
  protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
    FilterResults results) 
          {
           frndArrList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
           notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of your `publishResults` method. You are assigning frndArrList to be the results of your search, which means after you input a search, you actually remove all references to the data that was in your origin array list. To fix this, you need to change the following:

```
public int getCount() {
    return filterArrList.size()
}

//...

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_view, parent, false);
    TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.inflate_txtView);
    //txtView.setText(frndArrList.get(position));
    txtView.setText(filterArrList.get(position));

    return view;
}

//...

protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) 
            {
                filterArrList= (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor do not assign the reference to both the lists.

```
    public FriendListAdapter(MainActivity context, ArrayList<String> frndArrList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.frndArrList = frndArrList;
        this.filterArrList.addAll(frndArrList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create two different arraylist for search operation in adapter.
One is original and other is temp.
Make sure that not to create list with same reference.
You have to use this temp List to filter tax and to get compare operation use original arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on textchanged listener to filter a new list on text changed call of editext.

```
edit_searchbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            // get the text in the EditText
            String searchString = edit_searchbox.getText().toString();
            int textLength = searchString.length();

            // clear the initial data set
            searchResults.clear();

            String playerName="";
            for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {
                if(isContent){
                 playerName = aa.get(i).getComment().toString();}
                else{
                     playerName = aa.get(i).getTitle_txt().toString();}

                if (textLength <= playerName.length()) {
                    // compare the String in EditText with Names in the
                    //aa--- ArrayList
                    if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName
                            .substring(0, textLength)))
                        searchResults.add(aa.get(i));
                }
            }
            adapter = new NotepadAdapter(MemoActivity.this,
                    R.layout.listitem, searchResults);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```